# Fetch a variable from external javascript to execute inside a script block in body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I have an external javascript file,say, `first.js` which contains a variable named "score". I want to use this variable inside a `<script>` tag in body ( only after the variable has finished updating inside the first.js, in other words, I also want to control when this `<script>` inside body fires and obviously, use "score" in it ) . Any way to do so? 
EDIT-------
Basically I want to store this variable to the data browser in [parse.com](http://parse.com) . Here is my script--

```
    <script>

function giveit(){

var temp=whatScore();



Parse.initialize("myID", "myJDID");


var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var gameScore = new GameScore();

gameScore.set("score", temp);

gameScore.save(null, {
  success: function(gameScore) {
    // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
    alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);
  },
  error: function(gameScore, error) {
    // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
    alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
  }
});



}

</script>
```

`giveit()` function gets called when a button gets clicked. I have used the onlogin attribute.
Now `whatScore()` is a function defined in `first.js` which looks as follows:

```
function whatScore()
{
return score;
}
```

I stored the result in temp and used the temp in the code below, but it doesn't work.
In the console it says, "whatScore" is not defined. What can I do so that the whatScore function of `first.js` is actually defined inside the `<script>` tag ??
Thank You.

Comment: My partner has edited the code. Please see the script. Any other way of storing the "score" variable to parse.com may also be suggested. Thank You.

Comment: @ejay_francisco , this is parse.com script

Comment: Hi, I previously updated my code my answer.
Please, see the changed code.

Answer (score 2):

With this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="first.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body><script type="text/javascript">console . log ( { foo : score } );</script></body>
</html>
```

and file named: "first.js" content:

```
var score = 5;
```

I get in console:

```
Object { foo: 5 }
```

Make sure:

1. Your HTML5 / CSS3 / JavaScipt syntax is valid.
2. The variable score is in global scope.
3. The file named: "first.js" is loaded before your script tag and the variable score is declared and set before you use it.

You can also wait for variable using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function logScore () { console . log ( { foo : score } ); }
            var interval = setInterval ( function ()
            {
                if ( typeof score !== "undefined" ) // if is declared use variable named: "score" and exit interval
                {
                    logScore ();
                    clearInterval ( interval );
                }
            }, 1000 ); // wait one second ...
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">var score = 5; /* score loaded after interval */ </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="giveit ();">Test your function here ...</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function giveit ()
            {
                var interval = setInterval ( function ()
                {
                    if ( typeof whatScore === "function" ) // now check if function is declared, use return variable named: "score" and exit interval
                    {
                        var temp = whatScore ();
                        console . log ( { foo : temp } ); // log: Object { foo: 5 }
                        /* your code here */
                        clearInterval ( interval );
                    }
                }, 1000 ); // wait one second ...
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var score = 5; /* set global variable named: "score" - loaded after interval */
            function whatScore ()
            {
                // var score = 5 /* or set local variable named: "score" - loaded after interval */
                return score;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Please see the edit I have made. I am very close. Please help me. Thank You.